# Formulas within a table that reference an external workbook cause warning message when updating links

Tags: excel-formula

If I add a formula referencing another workbook, and the formula is within a table, the warning message "Warning: Open source to update values" is displayed when manually updating links.

I am using Excel 2010, but I can also observe the same behavior using Excel 2013.

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

- Create a workbook named A.xlsx and save it to your desktop.
- Create a workbook named B.xlsx and save it to your desktop.
- Open B.xlsx and insert a table on any spreadsheet. On any column of the table, add a formula that references A.xlsx, e.g. a formula directly refencing a cell on A.xlsx.
- On the Data tab, in the Connections group, click Edit Links. Chose A.xlsx as the source and click on "Update Values". The warning message "Warning: Open source to update values" is displayed.

  All the values seem to be updated without errors, despite the warning message.

  Question: Is this warning message spurious, or does it really indicate a failure to update the linked values in any way?

  As noted above, the values seem to be correctly updated in my tests, but the warning message is still a bit disturbing as it may indicate some issue I was not able to detect.

Answer (score 0):

If I précis what is detailed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925893/en-us) I may corrupt the proper explanation but as I understand it, basically this is to warn you that the workbook in which you see this message is using values stored in that workbook to represent those linked to in the other workbook. If the other workbook is closed the stored values may not have been updated by changes in the other workbook so to be sure open the other workbook to refresh the links.

If the other workbook is actually open at the time then I presume it is either an anomaly of Tables or perhaps a warning to cover a situation such as a link to an ‘open’ PivotTable but one that may not be in a refreshed state.

As far as the workbook with the warning is concerned the data is 'clean' but it is unable to read 'dirty' flags in the other workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only a recent user, and i was experiencing the same thing- after some research i came across this code- 
I adapted it for my own workbook and pasted it in the "ThisWorkbook" object in VBA for the destination workbook.
What it does is temporarily open/refresh/save and close the source application. If the connection to your source file is ok, it shouldn't take too long to update, but do be careful while trying to open it without a connection.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\address_of_source_workbook")

Dim i As Integer


For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count


ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i).Refresh

Next i
Workbooks("name_of_source_workbook").Save
Workbooks("name_of_source_workbook").Close
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!